# Get a list of valuesd based on lookup selection in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, report, hockeyapp

Hm. It's hard for me to write what I would like to accomplish.

I would like to make gamereport in Google spreadsheet for our Hockey Tournament. I would like to have all players attending our tournament in one sheet. Name, Number and Club. On game report sheet I would want to choose a club from a dropdown menu, and players would be inserted upon this query as a list.

Is it possible to do something like this in google spreadsheets?
Further more, I would like to have a sum of all goals and assist on players sheet.

Till now we have made this all by hand in Excel. Is it possible to have one sheet just for all the players? So If something changes I can change it only in one place?

You can try to help me. I have made one sheetpublic:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArUVg6g8Zlp-dFFpdEYzN1BSSjBnMmhfREdxbDczRHc&usp=sharing

Please help me make this? Any guidelines would be more than welcome. I know I should give this some to make it for money, but we can not afford it. We barely cope to get the season trough.

I would be more than grateful if you can help me.
Regards
Gregor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the items you are looking for is the filter function.

I've created a similar spreadsheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tE80u93n3SLiXmiBSQ5tc65wFHw6xVoQVHZlKEYQpqs/edit?usp=sharing

in A9 you'd want to add something similar to

```
=filter(Players!A2:D100,Players!E2:E100=A7)
```

You'd also want to ensure the range you are filtering is in a similar format to the location it is going to (i.e. merged cells).

Now the spreadsheet will adjust the players based on the team selected in the drop down.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's great. Just what I wanted. Now do you have any idea how to sum if a playernumber is entered in coloumn E? A goal scorer or Assist 1 or assist 2 have 1 point. Is it possible to add a sum to each player. And just one more question. Is it possible to have a global list of players? Or is better to create 26 reports (there is 26 games on tournament) in one Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: I have made a copy of your Spreadsheet. How to sum points and penalty minutes per player? Is it even possible? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11DzrDhWs-hPq10ehl5ObCJRVmiSifv7v2BNKaOJZTYU/edit?usp=sharing